# How to lag number of days instead of number of rows - for every ID

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am doing a classification problem in which I am trying to predict whether a car will be refuelled the following day.

The data consists of a date, an ID for every car, the distance to destination

What I want is a variable that is lagged 3 days, and not 3 rows per car_ID - since the case is that every car_ID is not present on every day. Therefore, the lag should be based on the date and not the rows.

If there are less than 3 days of history, the result should be -1.

Currently, I have this piece of code which lags every row 3 days

```
data['distance_to_destination'].groupby(data['car_ID']).shift(3).tolist()
```

But this is only lagging for the number of rows and not the number of days.

What I want to achieve is the column "lag_dtd_3":

```
date    car_ID  distance_to_destination lag_dtd_3

01/01/2019  1   100 -1

01/01/2019  2   200 -1

02/01/2019  1   80  -1

02/01/2019  2   170 -1

02/01/2019  3   500 -1

03/01/2019  2   120 -1

05/01/2019  1   25  80

05/01/2019  2   75  170

06/01/2019  1   20  -1

06/01/2019  2   30  120

06/01/2019  3   120 -1
```

Comment: What should happen if the history goes back 3 or more days, but there were no results from exactly 3 days ago?

Comment: Then the value should be -1. This is the case for car_ID == 3 above

Answer (score 0):

One solution to lag information by 3 days is to move the index instead of shifting.

```
pivot = data.pivot(columns='car_ID')
shifted = pivot.copy()
shifted.index = shifted.index + pd.DateOffset(days=3) # Here I lag the index instead of shifting

shifted.columns = shifted.columns.set_levels(['lag_dtd_3'], 0)
output = pd.concat([pivot, shifted], axis = 1).stack('car_ID').reset_index('car_ID')
output['lag_dtd_3'] = output['lag_dtd_3'].fillna(-1)
output = output.dropna()
```

Output:

```
    car_ID  distance_to_destination lag_dtd_3
date            
2019-01-01  1   100.0   -1.0
2019-01-01  2   200.0   -1.0
2019-01-02  1   80.0    -1.0
2019-01-02  2   170.0   -1.0
2019-01-02  3   500.0   -1.0
2019-01-03  2   120.0   -1.0
2019-01-05  1   25.0    80.0
2019-01-05  2   75.0    170.0
2019-01-06  1   20.0    -1.0
2019-01-06  2   30.0    120.0
2019-01-06  3   120.0   -1.0
```